# Increasing Function $\implies$ Positive Derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

If $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ and is differentiable in $(a, b)$, then $f'(x)>0$ in $(a, b)$.

My thoughts: Even if a function is increasing, it can be increasing on the $2$nd and $3$rd quadrant, so the derivative can be negative.

Comment: I think you might be confused on what "increasing" means intuitively - even in the 2nd and 3rd quadrants, increasing still implies that the function goes up and to the right - as it characteristic of having positive derivative. It seems like you might be thinking a function going up and to the left is increasing, but it's not - increasing isn't "gets bigger as we go away from $0$" but rather "gets bigger as the input does"

Comment: @MiloBrandt: In my experience, this is not a confusion, but just another difference between the perspective of college-level mathematics and pre-college-level mathematics. Ii't s a highly naive point of view, of course, and inhibits the development of the theory, but I've seen it promulgated in curricular material. It's along the same line as not considering a rectangle to be a parallelogram.

Answer (score 4):

Can't be negative, but it might be $0$; *viz*. $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$, with derivative equal to $0$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

recall the definition of derivative is

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

since $f(x)$ is increasing, therefore $$f(x+h)-f(x) \geq 0, \quad \forall h: 0<h<b-a$$